# Unterschied zwischen "derzeit" und "zurzeit"

Tags: adverb

Ich kann nicht verstehen, wieso die Personen hier in Baden-Württemberg mich verstehen, wenn ich "zurzeit" benutze, während sie mich nicht verstehen, wenn ich "derzeit" benutze.

Beispiel:

> derzeit kann ich nicht

Haben sie mich angesehen, als hätten sie mich nicht verstanden. Wenn ich ihnen danach gesagt habe

> zurzeit kann ich nicht

haben sie verstanden und gesagt "verstanden, ok, zurzeit kannst du nicht!".

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen diesen zwei Adverbien?

Comment: *derzeit* kann sich auch auf die Vergangenheit beiziehen, vielleicht hat das ein Missverständnis nach sich gezogen?

Comment: Da ich noch die alte Rechtschreibung gebrauche, mutet mir das klein- und zusammengeschriebene „zurzeit“ anstelle von „zur Zeit“ befremdlich an, weswegen ich nur „derzeit“ verwende. Zudem gibt es kein von dem Adverb „zurzeit“ („zurzeitig“) gebildetes Adjektiv, wie „derzeitig“ von „derzeit“.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Derzeit` and `zurzeit` are in fact synonyms. However, in South-German areas you should always use `zurzeit` cause the majority of people will understand it as kind of formal, mad or even snooty to use `derzeit`. This is just a dialect thing.

A dialog between friends:

> "Gehen wir ins Kino?"
>
> "Ich muss zurzeit leider viel lernen."

A dialog between a person who's either mad at or not well-known to the asker:

> "Gehen wir ins Kino?"
>
> "Ich muss derzeit leider viel lernen."

---

It's comparable to `Du` and `Sie`. If you use `Sie` in a non-formal context in South-Germany, the dialog partner will think that you don't really want to interact with him (you don't like him etc.).

Answer (score 5):

Laut Duden kann man beide Formen synonym verwenden, in seiner veralteten Form ist "derzeit" allerdings auch auf die Vergangenheit beziehbar.

Da der SWR das Wort für seinen Baden-Württembergischen Teil [ebenfalls verwendet](http://www.swr.de/swr4/bw/programm/spatz/heidenheim/herbrechtingen-wovon-gibt-es-derzeit-rund-eine-viertel-million/-/id=2372264/did=7806178/nid=2372264/ws105f/index.html), ist nicht davon auszugehen, dass das Wort in jenem Teile Deutschlands grundsätzlich unbekannt ist. Vielleicht war es in der konkreten Situation missverständlich oder undeutlich ausgesprochen?

Answer (score 1):

Als Muttersprachler würde ich sagen, dass die beiden Wörter "derzeit" und "zurzeit" Synonyme sind, d. h., dass sie dasselbe bedeuten. Wenn du also den Satz

> Derzeit kann ich nicht.

aussprichst, dann hast du alles richtig gemacht und ich vermute 'mal, dass die meisten Deutschen dich verstehen würden.

Comment: ...bis auf die Baden-Würtemberger, um die es in der Frage geht...

Comment: Nein, die Frage ist, ob es einen Unterschied zwischen "derzeit" und "zurzeit" gibt. Die Antwort dieser Frage hängt nicht vom Bundesland ab, da überall dieselbe Sprache, deutsch, gesprochen wird. Es kann aber natürlich sein, dass das Adverb "derzeit" nicht so üblich ist.

Comment: Stimmt, die Frage ist, ob es einen Unterschied zwischen "derzeit und "zurzeit" gibt. Die Frage kam aber auf, weil "derzeit" in BaWü nicht verstanden wurde. Da fand ich Deine Antwort "dass die meisten Deutschen dich verstehen würden" nicht so zielführend, daher mein Kommentar.

Comment: @Arsak, na ja, alle Deutschen abzüglich derjenigen aus BaWü sind immer noch die meisten Deutschen. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe 'der Zeit' is erroneusly understood as a contraction of 'in der Zeit'? The listener might try to parse this as a fragment of 'Ich kann [in]der Zeit [von ... bis]' nicht' and can't process the sentence because they believe they're missing information.

Comment: I believe you are on the right track here... look at the different pronunciation (emphasis) of *derzeit* (**[ˈdeːɐ̯ʦaɪ̯t]**) vs. *zurzeit* (**[ʦʊʁˈʦaɪ̯t]**). If we got that wrong it may lead to confusion. Care to [edit] this into your answer?

Comment: @Takkat Just for clarification, making sure I understand you correctly - is this what you mean: The stress on the first syllable in _derzeit_ could potentially be misunderstood as an emphasis on a particular time frame, e.g.  'in _der_ Zeit', whereas there is less potential for confusion with _zurzeit_.

Comment: Not quite... the appropriate stress always is on the first syllable ***der**-zeit*. If we erroneously pronounce it on the second syllable *der-**zeit*** it may not be well understood. *Zur-**zeit*** always is stressed on the second syllable.

Answer (score -2):

Zurzeit und derzeit sind im Deutschen Synonyme. Eigentlich sollten die meisten Deutschen beide Begriffe gut verstehen. Weitere Informationen zum Begriff zurzeit findest du auch [hier](https://nikolai-sroka.de/zurzeit-schreibweise-getrennt-oder-zusammen/).

Comment: Ich dachte immer, SEO wäre ein Schimpfwort. Tapfer, es als Selbstbezeichnung zu verwenden.

Comment: Was versprechen Sie sich davon, nach fast 7 Jahren die bereits gegebenen Antworten auf die Frage quasi nochmal zu wiederholen?